# Change permalink from wp_list_categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

**UPDATE 23/05**

Now im using this, its 95% completed,

Now i need to put:

```
<li class="child">Subcategory title </li>
```

on child elements of this categories, and its done :)

Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$cat_name = 'onde-encontrar';
$category = get_category_by_slug( $cat_name );
$taxonomy_name = 'category';
$term_ids = get_term_children( $category->term_id, $taxonomy_name );
foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
    echo "<li class='cat-item'><a title='title' class='smoothScroll' name='{$term->term_id}' href='#{$term->term_id}'>{$term->name}</a></li>";
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

This helped me:

```
$cat_name = 'onde-encontrar';
$category = get_category_by_slug( $cat_name );
$taxonomies = array( 'category' );
$args = array( 'parent' => $category->term_id );
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomies, $args );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
echo "<a title='title' href='www.era420/category/{$cat_name}/#{$term->term_id}'>{$term->name}</a>";
}
```

But dont print **subcategories**, and i want to print subcategories too.

Someone can help me?

Thanks so much

**OLD:**

I have this code that works perfectly for what I want, but I want the link that shows the wp_list_categories, is the id of the category and not the permalink.
For desire that when you click on the category it scroll down and does not change the main page ...

My code:

```
<?php
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'onde-encontrar' );
wp_list_categories('title_li=&child_of='.$category->term_id);
?>
```

What shows me:

```
<a title="title" href="www.era420/category/onde-encontrar/sao-paulo/">São Paulo</a>
```

What i want:

```
 <a title="title" href="www.era420/category/onde-encontrar/#33">São Paulo</a>
```

something like that,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating the list using a custom function instead of the `wp_list_categories()` function.

```
$cat_name = 'onde-encontrar';
$category = get_category_by_slug( $cat_name );
$taxonomy_name = 'category';
$term_ids = get_term_children( $category->term_id, $taxonomy_name );
foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
    echo "<a title='title' href='www.era420/category/{$cat_name}/#{$term->term_id}'>{$term->name}</a>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. If you use [`get_term_children(`)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) it should do the trick, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect! :) Last thing: 
How can i put a different class on a element child(subcategories elements) ?

Comment: Yeap, can u help me? i updated my post, i need child categories come with class children or something like that....

Comment: At some point there is a line between helping someone learn how to do something and just doing work for free :p I would recommend asking a new question regarding how to tell if a term is a sub category or not and include the code/research tried so far. Google can probably even point you to the answer.